# What makes verifyClient in cffunction secure?

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, security

What does verifyClient in `<cffunction>` actually do that makes it secure? secure from what?

Doc said:

> A Boolean value that specifies whether
>   to require remote function calls to
>   include an encrypted security token.
>   For use with ColdFusion AJAX
>   applications only.

encrypted security token?  who generates that?  Client-side by JS?  Injected to JS on page request by CF?  What if another person uses the same security token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the generated source, the _cf_clientid is a string of hexadecimal generated by ColdFusion and injected to the client's JavaScript.

Seems like that ID will be compared with the CFID and CFTOKEN if session management is enabled.

I opened another browser and go to the same URL (GET), and the server replies a HTTP 500 internal server error.

Comment: Is this only usable if you are using cfajaxproxy?  I would like to implement this in my ExtJS application, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Yes, cfajaxproxy or cf8 ajax components like CFGrid or CFinput bind to a CFC

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to figure something else out then!